# Improving tag for fanmade game

Tags: discussion, tags

I have stumbled upon [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254294/how-to-capture-legendary-pokemon-in-unovarpg)

While the question itself is absolutely valid, I disagree with tagging it as [pokemon-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-series) as it is not part of the original series and as the description states:

> This tag should be used in context of the actual series

So what would be better options for tagging that question?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that tag was used because the user who originally posted the question can't create tags. Since the tag for the specific game was added afterwards, the series tag isn't necessary, so I've removed it